# Saving value in string after selection with awt java

Tags: java, swing, awt

[image: my interface]

I have this interface that i am working on to show information about machines connected to my local network. I want to select an ip than click on "Plus dinformation" button to show some information related to this machine. Here is my selection code

```
 final static JTextArea clien = new JTextArea(20,30);
 clien.setSelectionColor(Color.blue);

 clien.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        MouseReleased(evt);
     }

    private void MouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         strselection = clien.getSelectedText();
}
```

When i select an IP and then press the information button, the value contained in `strselection` found is `null` because clicking on that button cancelled the selection. I want that selection to remain active after clicking the button so `strselection` does not become `null`. How can i tweak my selection code to make this possible. I tried but with no luck.

Comment: You should use a `JList` instead.

Comment: For this purpose I think would be better if you can use a `JList` instead `JTextArea`. Then your selection will remain active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a `JList` instead of a `JTextArea`. It will allow multiple selections and retain the selection even when pressing any button. Adding the `JList` into a `JScrollPane` will make it scrollable too.

You will have to add a listener on the buttons instead of the `JList` and each action performed will check the selected items in the `JList`.

Comment: No, he could add a `ListSelectionListener` to his `JList`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a JTextArea. Use a JComboBox or something like that where a user selects one value out of a list of values.

What if, in your example above, I selected two ip-adresses and pressed the button?

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

EDIT: Or JList, that works too.

Comment: In this case, it seems `JComboBox` would be impractical, `JList` would be a better alternative.